# Complex if statements are not simulatable

Tags: vhdl

I intend to summerize many if statements into one (in VHDL), like:

from this working snippet

```vhdl
if config = "0001" and counter = 40 then
    res <= '1';
elsif config = "0010" and counter = 52 then
    res <= '1';
else
    res <= '0';
end if;
```

to this unworking snippet

```vhdl
if config = "0001" and counter = 40 or config = "0010" and counter = 52 then
    res <= '1';
else
    res <= '0';
end if;
```

Vivado tells me "there is a problem near 'or'", but I don't see one.

Will this be better (more robust) on hardware implementation?

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps parenthesize the terms?

Comment: I tried, it does not work

Comment: The VHDL operators `and` and `or` have the same order of precedence, so without the required parenthesis described by user1155120, it could easily be unclear if `A or B and C` is intended to mean `A or (B and C)` or `(A or B) and C`.  In for example Python the `and` operator has higher precedence than `or` operator, so `A or B and C` is equivalent with `A or (B and C)`.  The required parenthesis in VHDL makes the language less error prone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), e.g.:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity unworking_snippet is
end entity;

architecture snippet of unworking_snippet is
    signal config:  bit_vector (3 downto 0) := "0001";
    signal counter: integer range 0 to 52 := 40;
    signal res:  std_logic;
begin

    process  (config, counter)
    begin

        if config = "0001" and counter = 40 or config = "0010" and counter = 52 then
            res <= '1';
        else
            res <= '0';
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Which will produce an error message pointing to your if statement. ghdl for example points to two errors in the if statement:

```
ghdl -a unworking_snippet.vhdl
unworking_snippet.vhdl:16:45:error: only one type of logical operators may be used to combine relation
unworking_snippet.vhdl:16:64:error: only one type of logical operators may be used to combine relation
ghdl:error: compilation error
```

where line 16 contains the if statement condition, character 45 is the 'o' in `or` and character 64 is the 'a' in the second `and`.

These are hard coded into VHDL's expression parsing described in the Baccus Naur Form (BNF) in IEEE Std 1076-2008 9. Expressions, 9.1 General:

```
An expression is a formula that defines the computation of a value.
expression ::=
      condition_operator primary
    | logical_expression

logical_expression ::=
      relation { and relation }
    | relation { or relation }
    | relation { xor relation 
    | relation [ nand relation ]
    | relation [ nor relation ]
    | relation { xnor relation }

relation ::=
    shift_expression [ relational_operator shift_expression ]

shift_expression ::=
    simple_expression [ shift_operator simple_expression ]

simple_expression ::=
    [ sign ] term { adding_operator term }

term ::=  
    factor { multiplying_operator factor }

factor ::=
      primary [ ** primary ]  
    | abs primary
    | not primary
    | logical_operator primary  

primary ::=  
      name
    | literal
    | aggregate
    | function_call
    | qualified_expression
    | type_conversion
    | allocator
    | ( expression )
```

where you'll find by hand parsing the if statement condition the only way to have two different logical operators as relations in another logical operator is if the primary is contained in parentheses:

```vhdl
        if (config = "0001" and counter = 40) or (config = "0010" and counter = 52) then
```

The path through the BNF is relation => shift_expression => simple_expression => term => logical_operator primary, primary => (expression). This occurs for both sides of the `or` operator.

Substituting the updated if statement condition allows the MCVe to analyze  (compile) successfully.

While superfluous parentheses are often introduced by those with programming backgrounds parentheses are required for different logical operators in the same expression (`config = "0001" and counter = 40 or config = "0010" and counter = 52` in the original 'unworking' snippet).

Because it's a syntax analysis requirement in the BNF there can be no difference between simulation and post synthesis functionality.

VHDL treats logical operators with the same precedence:

9.2 Operators

9.2.1 General

> The operators that may be used in expressions are defined as follows. Each operator belongs to a class of operators, all of which have the same precedence level; the classes of operators are listed in order of increasing precedence.
>
> ...
>   logical_operator ::= **and** | **or** | **nand** | **nor** | **xor** | **xnor**
>
> relational_operator ::= = | /= | < | <= | > | >= | ?= | ?/= | ?< | ?<= | ?> | ?>=
>   ...
>
> Operators of higher precedence are associated with their operands before operators of lower precedence. Where the language allows a sequence of operators, operators with the same precedence level are associated with their operands in textual order, from left to right. The precedence of an operator is fixed and cannot be changed by the user, but parentheses can be used to control the association of operators and operands.
>
> In general, operands in an expression are evaluated before being associated with operators. For certain operations, however, the right-hand operand is evaluated if and only if the left-hand operand has a certain value. These operations are called short-circuit operations. The binary logical operations and, or, nand, and nor defined for operands of types BIT and BOOLEAN are all short-circuit operations; furthermore, these are the only short-circuit operations.

Here the language doesn't allow the sequence of operators based on the lack of precedence between logical operators.

9.1 paragraphs 3 & 4

> Each primary has a value and a type. The only names allowed as primaries are attributes that yield values and names denoting objects or values. In the case of names denoting objects other than objects of file types or protected types, the value of the primary is the value of the object. In the case of names denoting either file objects or objects of protected types, the value of the primary is the entity denoted by the name.
>
> The type of an expression depends only upon the types of its operands and on the operators applied; for an overloaded operand or operator, the determination of the operand type, or the identification of the overloaded operator, depends on the context (see 12.5). For each predefined operator, the operand and result types are given in the following subclause.

The following subclause is 9.2 and the type of expressions resulting from relational operators is type BOOLEAN (9.2.3 Relational operators).

The BNF restriction requiring parentheses avoids the complexity of evaluating an entire expression repetitively to determine it's tree structure without superimposing logical operator precedence on George Boole's algebra, noting expressions can also produced values of arbitrary types. There are no restrictions on the size or complexity of expressions and the parentheses imply sub-trees.

Comment: Your answere is very complete,
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to put parentheses like this:

```
if (config = "0001" and counter = 40) or (config = "0010" and counter = 52) then
    res <= '1';
else
    res <= '0';
end if;
```

On hardware implementation, I think the two codes will most likely infer the same components or the difference will be negligible.

Comment: Ops, this is true. I tried this many times and it did not work... I don't know what happened.
In another topic: if I put this as a function in a package, will it be the same hardware implementation? Thank you

Comment: The hardware implementation will (typically) be the same even if you wrap the operation in a function in a package.  As long as the circuit described by the VHDL code is the same, it does (typically) not matter how that circuit is described.  Tools (typically) converts the VHDL code to an internal circuit description early in the implementation flow, which dissolves any function or process wrapping.